# Wrong in convert four byte to integer then display in textbox

Tags: c#, string, textbox, arrays, int32

I use array of byte and I need to convert this 4 byte to integer and display result in textbox ,the result must 320 but it display 64

```
byte[] bb = new byte[4] { 64, 1, 0, 0 }; 
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(bb[0]).ToString(); // display result 64 it must 320
```

what is wrong??

Comment: I don't know why in the world you think it should be 320 even if it worked the way you're imagining. But you still only passed 1 byte to the method, with the value 64. How would it be anything else?

Comment: _I need to convert this 4 byte to integer_ But you are taking just first one..

Comment: it must give me width of image 320 not 64 is there other method for convert,can you give me other method for convert four byte to integer

Comment: What is wrong..?? your way of asking question is wrong..

Comment: Try BitConverter.ToInt32(bb , 0)

Comment: Your code does what you asked it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you need is [BitConverter.ToInt32()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Change the code such that:

```
byte[] bb = new byte[4] { 64, 1, 0, 0 }; 
textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToInt32(bb, 0).ToString();
```

Note that BitConnverter takes a byte array and a start index.

In your example, you just have a 4 byte array. if you are going to read from a large array and convert the values one by one, make sure you pass the correct index to the ToInt32 method.